# Explanation of the Wolstenholme theorem proof

Tags: number-theory, binomial-coefficients, proof-explanation

I recently came accross the Wolstenholme theorem which says that $$\binom{ap}{bp} \equiv \binom{a}{b} \pmod {p^{3}}$$ 
On [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolstenholme%27s_theorem), it gives a combinatorial proof of this theorem that involves splitting a set A of size ap into a rings of size p, but I don't understand the rest of the proof. Can someone help breakdown the group theory in that proof? I'm familiar with what a direct sum and what the cyclic group is, but I don't understand this proof.